# Grey to Binary Image using R

Tags: r

Is there any R function to convert grey scale image to binary image. There is one to convert from RGB to Grey but I want to convert Grey to Binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say what class or "typeof" your data is, so I'm going to provide an answer in a simple case.  Suppose your image is an array of integers. These integers range from 0 to, say 512 for a 9-bit greyscale image.  You need to decide what the cutoff point is for 0 vs. 1 in your binary image.  Then

`bin_image <- round(grey_image/max(grey_image),0)`

should do it. If your data range from 0 to 1, do a similar operation but adjust the rounding parameters.
Edit: ooops, I left out a choice of cutoff level.  Replace `max(grey_image)` with `K*max(grey_image)` where `K = 1` for cutting at half-max, `K>1` to cut higher and `K<1` to cut lower.

Comment: I am using ReadImages packages to read .jpg file. It is the RGB file and I am converting it to grey using rgb2grey(). I want to know is there any function to convert this grey image to binary without rounding. Rounding itself is setting a cutoff at 0.5 is not it?

Comment: @Joy, yes, that's what rounding will do.  What is your definition of "binary" ?  I thought you meant you wanted two levels: 0 and 1, and no other in the final result.

Comment: Well, that's the definition of "rounding" .

Answer (score 4):

This is called thresholding or binarization. The most robust in my experience is [adaptive thresholding](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/adpthrsh.htm). This is implemented in `EBImage` as the `thresh` method

```
x = readImage(system.file('images', 'nuclei.tif', package='EBImage'))
if (interactive()) display(x)
y = thresh(x, 10, 10, 0.05)
if (interactive()) display(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [EBImage](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.10/bioc/html/EBImage.html) Bioconductor package is a handy tool for performing image analysis in R.
A basic example taken from the package's Vignette:

```
lena = readImage(system.file("images", "lena.gif", package="EBImage"))
display(lena>0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks both of you for the answer. Now I have the idea to move further.